# How to programmatically open Android soft keyboard according to the html input type in android webview

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview, android-keypad

I want to show android soft keyboard on page load and programmatically focusing a input field.

```
$('#field').focus();
```

As far as I researched , this cannot be done other than user generated events , like click event.

So I tried a workaround to focus the input field , and show android keyboard manually by using this code.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(myWebView.getWindowToken() , InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT , 0);
```

Keyboard is successfully showing and input field is also getting focus. But the problem is , it is only showing the standard keyboard. I want to show the keyboard according to the input type specified.

Like if input field is:

```
<input type="number" id="field" name="field"/>
```

Above workaround is showing standard text keyboard , but I want to show a numeric keyboard according to the type in input field.

Comment: did u find the solution..???

Answer (score 1):

i've searched a long time before i found solution.

Add this :

```
imm.restartInput(view);
```

after showSoftInput.

This will "recalculate" the kind of keyboard to show regarding focused input

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

Comment: This will show or hide the soft keyboard, but OP is asking how to change the layout from alpha to numeric.